# Related posts with Gatsby.js and Graphql

Tags: javascript, graphql, gatsby

I am relatively new to GraphQL and this is the first site I'm building with this. So I'm trying to have a few posts displayed which are markdown files, this works well.

On top of that I'd like a "join" on the posts that have the same "category" but a different "language". Can I do this in the pageQuery? I need the "category" and one other field that is returned in the first part of the query.

The desired result is to have the markdown document found by id or slug and then to have in a sidebar (like on wikipedia): Read this page in:

- Spanish
- German

and so on.

Here's what my frontmatter block looks like:

```
---
title: "Street Photography Laws in Germany"
date: "2018-12-24"
lastmod: "2019-04-02"
description: "What's legal to shoot in Germany doing street photography and where?"
featured_image: "cover-laws.jpg"
layout: "country"
country: "Germany"
type: "law"
category: "street"
slug: "street-photography-laws-in-germany"
langKey: "en"
---
```

This is what my "single post" query looks like:

```
query($path: String!) {
    markdownRemark(fields: { path: { eq: $path } }) {
      html
      fileAbsolutePath
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        lastmod(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        featured_image
        title
        country
        type
      }
      fields {
        path
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: there're a few ways you can do this, but how will you identify the same article in different languages?

Comment: @DerekNguyen Hi Derek! There's only one post per category, per country, per language, so I don't have a problem with identifying the right post in another language.